# Streaming from Pub/Sub to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to stream some data from google PubSub into BigQuery using a python dataflow.
For testing purposes I have adapted the following code https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master/python/dataflow_examples/cookbook/bigquery_schema.py into a streaming pipeline by setting

```
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
```

So then I changed the record_ids pipeline to read from Pub/Sub

```
# ADDED THIS
lines = p | 'Read PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadStringsFromPubSub(INPUT_TOPIC) | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(15))
# CHANGED THIS # record_ids = p | 'CreateIDs' >> beam.Create(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
record_ids = lines | 'Split' >> (beam.FlatMap(split_fn).with_output_types(unicode))
records = record_ids | 'CreateRecords' >> beam.Map(create_random_record)
records | 'Write' >> beam.io.Write(
    beam.io.BigQuerySink(
        OUTPUT,
        schema=table_schema,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
```

Note: I have been whitelisted by google to run the code (in alpha)

Now when I try it I have an error

Workflow failed. Causes: (f215df7c8fcdbb00): Unknown streaming sink: bigquery

You can find the full code here: https://github.com/marcorigodanzo/gcp_streaming_test/blob/master/my_bigquery_schema.py

I think that this has to do with the pipeline being now of type streaming, can anyone please tell me how to do a bigQuery write in a streaming pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

Beam Python does not support writing to BigQuery from streaming pipelines. For now, you will need to use Beam Java - you can use respectively `PubsubIO.readStrings()` and `BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()`.

Comment: OK, thank you Eugene. I was hoping to use python. Do you know if this will change in the future? Can you also address me to an example of code reading from Pub/Sub and writing to BigQuery in java?

Comment: I believe this example uses both https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java8/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/LeaderBoard.java. Yes, Python will eventually catch up with Java (potentially via Beam's currently-in-development portability framework which will allow Python pipelines to use Java transforms), but I can't predict what the timeline will be.