# Python SDK Streaming Dataflow Runner

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow written in Python that I am trying to run on GCP.  The dataflow keeps terminating with:

Workflow failed. Causes: Unknown message code.

The main code in my dataflow pipeline is:

```py
schema = 'Member_ID:INTEGER,First_Name:STRING,Last_Name:STRING,Gender:STRING,Age:INTEGER,Height:STRING,weight:INTEGER,Hours_Sleep:INTEGER,Calories_Consumed:INTEGER,Calories_Burned:INTEGER,Evt_Date:DATE,Height_Inches:INTEGER,Min_Sleep_Hours:INTEGER,Max_Sleep_Hours:INTEGER,Enough_Sleep:BOOL'

# read, transform and local source data
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

# Read from PubSub into a PCollection.
events = (p | 'Read PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub (topic='projects/prefab-envoy-220213/topics/health_event')
            | 'Parse CSV' >> beam.ParDo(getCSVFields())
            | 'Convert Types' >> beam.ParDo(ConvDataTypes())
            | 'Convert Height' >> beam.ParDo(ConvHeight())
            | 'Join CDC Sleep' >> beam.ParDo(CDCSleepJoin(), cdcsleep)
            | 'Create Row' >> beam.ParDo(CreateRow()) 
            | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                    'prefab-envoy-220213:nhcdata.nhcevents', schema=schema,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED))
)

results = p.run()
results.wait_until_finish()
```

If I delete the

```py
            | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                    'prefab-envoy-220213:nhcdata.nhcevents', schema=schema,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED))
```

then the dataflow starts ok.

Answer (score 1):

`beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink())` is a native Dataflow sink and it only works for batch jobs. For streaming pipelines you should use [`beam.io.WriteToBigQuery()`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.8.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery) instead. Usage:

```py
beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table ='table_name',dataset='dataset',project='project_id')
```

You can find a good example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51649155/6121516).